# COMMIT in Teradata Ansi Session Mode

Tags: commit, teradata

I have a requirement to pull data from Teradata to which I am connected in ANSI session mode. 
The Teradata version is below 14, and therefore doesn't support more than one derived table using 'WITH' clause. Because of this limitation I am forced to create a temporary table, to which I load the data,and would like to use the data from the temp table. However, I get the

> 3722 ERROR :  Only a COMMIT WORK or null statement is legal after a
>   DDL Statement

I tried having a *COMMIT*, *COMMIT WORK*, *SELECT null* and all of these keep throwing the same error. Note that I can't use BT; ET; since I am not on TERADATA session. And it isn't supported on ANSI session.

This is the simplified version of the query that I would like to get working.

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE temp_table AS
(SELECT col FROM my_table)
WITH DATA
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
COMMIT; -- COMMIT; / COMMIT;/COMMIT WORK;/;
SELECT * FROM temp_table;
```

Any ideas on how I could get this working?

P.S : And yes, I would have to have the CREATE AND SELECT statement in a single request. It's a restriction we have because of the way we have our ETL process set up.

Comment: There's no way to submit this as a multi-statement request. But why don't you simply use Derived Tables instead of WITH?

Comment: It's a huge table that I am selecting from. And when used as a derived table, I get "No more spool space" error.
This is kinda what a part of my query looks like. 
` SELECT col from tbl1 WHERE col1 IN (temp_tbl)
UNION
SELECT col FROM tbl2 WHERE col1 NOT IN (temp_tbl);`

Comment: I have no way of increasing my spool space either, since the database is not in our control.

Comment: I would assume that the optimizer calculates the Derived Table only once (like WITH) and then uses it in both selects. But the NOT IN might get a bad plan (if there are NULLable columns, check Explain), rewriting to NOT EXISTS might help in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any way to change the session mode from ANSI to TERADATA, that would be the easiest solution.

Otherwise, you can try to split this in a CREATE TABLE ...  WITH NO DATA statement, then a COMMIT WORK, and then an INSERT statement.

PS.: You didn't mention about data distribution, but if the selected table has a poor distribution I would create the temporary table with no primary index.